# Android Get Current Date (with time being 0:00:000) in Milliseconds?

Tags: android, date, time

I would like to get the current date with the time zeroed out in milliseconds.

Example, if it's 12:69pm today, I want to get the time in milliseconds for today's date with no time...meaning, the time just after midnight (one millisecond or 0 if that works).

I was using the Calendar object but can't seem to figure out how to zero out the time portion.

Comment: Can you elaborate your question suppose now the time is 7:08:08 now what the output should be for you

Comment: By the way, you must have a really strange clock if it displays "12:69" :p

Comment: @Jave - LOL...sorry, I was typing fast and the time wasn't important...ha ha. This is really funny though. :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here is how to zero the time of a calendar:

```
Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
today.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
today.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
today.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
today.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

And without calendar:

```
long d = new Date().getTime();
int offset = TimeZone.getDefault().getOffset(d);
d = ((d + offset)/ 86400000l) * 86400000l - offset;
```